# Finding words frequency of huge data in a database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, full-text-search

If we have a huge string data in a file, we can normally use algorithm(s), say (hash + heap) or (trie + heap), etc etc to efficiently find the top 'k' words with high frequency. How do I do this if I have a huge amount of string data in my 'database'. Right now the only way I know is to query the entire data set and then implement the frequency operations on it. But querying the huge data set is a very costly operation. Is there any efficient/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding information on huge data is done by parallelizing it and use a cluster rather then a single machine.

What you are describing is a classic [map-reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) problem, that can be handled using the following functions (in pseudo code):

```
map(doc):
  for each word in doc:
      emitIntermediate(word,"1")
reduce(list<word>):
  emit(word,size(list))
```

The map reduce framework, which is implemented in many languages - allows you to easily scale the problem and use a huge cluster without much effort, taking care of failures and workers management for you.

In here: doc is a single document, it usually assumes a collection of documents. If you have only one huge document, you can of course split it to smaller documents and invoke the same algorithm.

Comment: I dont have much knowledge of parallel computing or creating clusters. Can you provided me reference links to how mapreduce can be implemented using clusters? I basically want to know, how to use an already existing implementation of mapreduce(say java or ruby) with clusters.

Comment: @AmanSingh: Map-Reduce is already implemented. [The original paper](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) was implemented by Google in C++. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) is a popular Java implementation. Don't try to implement Map-Reduce on your own - use an existing framework.